# list comprehension with additional step (comparing first element to itself, then first with second, second with third,...) python

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension, timedelta

I've got a timestamp in the format %H:%M:%S. With the following function I get the elapsed time:

```
# time diff func
def time_diff(t1, t2):
return datetime.strptime(t1, '%H:%M:%S') - datetime.strptime(t2, '%H:%M:%S')

# elapsed time since start
data['time'] = [time_diff(data['time'][i], data['time'][0]) for i in range(len(data['time']))]
```

I also want to calculate the timedelta between consecutive data entries. So timedelta between first and second, second with third and so on... The following list comprehension does the job:

```
# get timedelta
timedeltas = [data['time'][i] - data['time'][i-1] for i in range(1 ,len(data['time']))]
```

The result starts with the timedelta between the first and the second entry. But I would like that the list comprehension starts with comparing the first entry with itself so I get 00:00:00 as first result and then starts to compare elements with the consecutive element (first with second, second with third,..). Has anybody an idea on how to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A very Pythonic method is to avoid using subsripting (slicing) at all, and just use the following:

```
[0] + [time_diff(t1, t0) for (t1, t0) in zip(data[1:], data[:-1])]
```

- The first difference is known to be 0 - you defined it that way.
- For the rest of the differences, we `zip` two sub-lists - one starting at second element element and continuing to the end, and the other starting at the first and continuing to the next ot last.
- Then, comprehend the zip of pairs (zip is a generator object, so no list of pairs is generated), and use the differences to construct the target list's second through last element.

You can improve performance and memory consumption by replacing `data[:-1]`. this will prevent creating a the temporary list `data[:-1]`, and will not change functionality, since `zip` operates only while neither list is exhausted. The code is a bit dirty, though (IMHO), because you send lists of unequal length to `zip`.

You could also skip the creation of the `data[1:]` temporary list, by doing:

```
data_i = iter(data)
next(data_i)
diff = [0] + [time_diff(t1, t0) for (t1, t0) in zip(data_i, data)]
```

Now you are using 3 lines of code, but are not creating any temporary list, nor accessing lists visa random access (only sequential access is used).

You can further simplify using `itertools.islice`:

```
from itertools import islice
diff = [0] + [time_diff(t1, t0) for (t1, t0) in zip(islice(data, 1, None), data)]
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your well-explained answer. Many thanks also for the further notes regarding the performance!

Answer (score 1):

Did you try

```
# get timedelta
timedeltas = [data['time'][i] - data['time'][i-1] if i > 0 else data['time'][i]-data['time'][i] for i in range(len(data['time']))]
```

?
It's pretty ugly though. I think the code

```
timedeltas = [data['time'][0]-data['time'][0]] + [data['time'][i] - data['time'][i-1] for i in range(1 ,len(data['time']))]
```

is more readable for this purpose

Comment: I was already thinking of this, but I was looking for a cleaner and better opportunity of doing it. Nevertheless many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this quite neatly with `pandas`:

```py
import pandas as pd

# I suppose your data is a dictionary
data = {'time': ['12:13:11', '12:14:15', '13:20:31']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)
df.time = pd.to_datetime(df.time)
df['timedeltas'] = df.time.diff() # Produces NaT to first index
df.timedeltas.fillna(pd.Timedelta(seconds=0), inplace=True) # Replaces NaT values with 0-second Timedelta

print(df)

>>> 
                 time timedeltas
0 2020-05-13 12:13:11   00:00:00
1 2020-05-13 12:14:15   00:01:04
2 2020-05-13 13:20:31   01:06:16
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you very much, didn't know this way of doing it!